# Can a Python descriptor's __set__ ever get called with instance = None?

Tags: python, descriptor

Imagine I've got this [Python descriptor](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.4/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class MyDesc(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):
        return 'Blue berries'
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print 'called with', instance, value

class MyClass(object):
    desc = MyDesc()
```

Is there a way in the normal run of things thar `__set__` would get called with `None` for an instance argument? I mean without doing something like

```
MyClass.__dict__['desc'].__set__(None, 'ants bees cats')
```

These don't seem to do it:

```
MyClass.desc = 'blah'
setattr(MyClass, 'desc', 'blah')
```

The reason I ask is I see some [defensive coding in Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L388) to avoid this scenario, and I'm questioning whether it's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right to question this test, and I can't find a way for `instance` to be `None` in this code either. The documentation also seems to make it clear that `instance` can never be `None`:

> ```
> object.__set__(self, instance, value)
> ```
>
> Called to set the attribute **on an instance `instance`** of the owner class to a new value, `value`.

My guess is that `instance` was checked for `None` in `__get__` for [a good reason](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__), and that the same test ended up in `__set__` by sheer mimetism.

Answer (score 0):

As for the defensive coding, I see some code checking that there's an instance on `__get__` (which gets called for `MyClass.desc`) but not on `__set__`. The reason it doesn't happen with `__set__` is that setting the reference in the class replaces the whole descriptor reference.

I'd advise against excessively defensive programming, simply because the other code can find any way to go wrong with or without your assistance. It's enough to prevent surprising results rather than guard against active abuse.